# ListView inside a TabController disappears when the TextView is focused

Tags: flutter

I found that if a ListView is inside a Tab Controller, the items inside the view disappears if a TextView is focused. Is this a bug?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new TextField(),
      new Expanded(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'Info'),
                  Tab(text: 'News'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(title: Text('row 1')),
                    ListTile(title: Text('row 2')),
                    ListTile(title: Text('row 3')),
                  ],
                ),
                Text("abc"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
}
```

As you can see from first picture below, the list view is originally shown. But after I click on the text field in picture 2, the list is disappeared.

[image]
[image]

Comment: your UI is weird, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can think of the textfield is for getting the user name. Then the tabs consist of categories of choices which can be used with the user name entered, e.g. a choice can be "create a japanese self-introductiion with your username". Notice that the textfield is not a search, because the choices are static (they apply to any values). Let me know if there is a better pattern I can follow. I will try out your solution tonight, thanks!

Comment: I already posted my solution without using two scaffolds . take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the same without using two scaffolds, take a look at this:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text("title test"),
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: TextField(),
                      ),
                      TabBar(
                        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(text: 'Info'),
                          Tab(text: 'News'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(title: Text('row 1')),
                      ListTile(title: Text('row 2')),
                      ListTile(title: Text('row 3')),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text("abc"),
                ],
              ),
              floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => null,
                tooltip: 'Increment',
                child: new Icon(Icons.add),
              ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
            ));
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use double scaffold if your are using and use

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

in your existing scaffold.